# Add multiple users to model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-2.1

I am creating a page where only a certain users can access, I would like to add them manualy, at the moment here is what I have

**models.py**

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
manager = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name="Manager d'équipe")
code = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Code hôtel", default="N/A")
contact_rh = models.EmailField(max_length=150,verbose_name="Contact RH", default="N/A")
contact_gm = models.EmailField(max_length=150,verbose_name="Contact GM", default="N/A")
payday = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Jour de paye prévu du mois")
hotel = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Nom de l'hôtel")
planning = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='Planning mois en cours')

def __str__(self):
    return self.hotel
```

But of course I cannot add more than one user I cannot figured out.

Thanks

Comment: You can use a `ManyToManyField` instead of a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: If you want to add multiple managers then you have to use ManyToManyField rather then ForeignKey

Comment: thanks, it is working and I added a context so only the users added to the model can see the page, thanks again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see previous answers, for that to work I had to change **ForeignKey** to **ManyToManyField** and for my purpose so only the users added can see the page I had to add the folowing code to my list views.py :

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.model.objects.filter(collaborateurs=self.request.user)
```